# WPF border failed to wrap Image nicely?

Tags: c#, wpf

```
<Border CornerRadius="3" BorderBrush="#fff" BorderThickness="3px" Width="100" Height="100">
    <Image Source="test.jpg" Width="100" Height="100"/>
</Border>
```

As shown in the code above, I've forced the Image to have 100 for both width and height as well as the border. My intention was so that the border can wrap the image without any unnecessary spaces. However please take a look at the result below:

[image: testing]

There are still unnecessary spaces between the border and image? **The problem can be solved by reducing the width and height of border** but I just don't understand why. Below is my original image where width and height larger than 100:

[image]

Comment: So whats the problem ? Or you just want to understand it?

Comment: @Gabson: Yes I just wanna understand it. Since both image and border have set 100, shouldn't the border wrap the image completely?

Comment: Your border IS the 3px white area around the image. What exactly do you need?

Comment: @Samuel: Yes the white border does shown up. But the white border doesn't wrap the image nicely. There are unecessary spaces at top and bottom cant you see it?

Comment: What you want to achive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*You* have set the `BorderBrush` property to `White` and the `BorderThickness` property to `3px` on your `Border`. I can only imagine that *that* explains the white line around the edge of the `Border`. Just remove these properties to remove the white surrounding line.

---

UPDATE >>>

I would agree with @GazTheDestroyer. If your image is actually wider than 100px, then it will be automatically resized to fit into the 94px. If your image is wider than it is tall, then that would account for the gap at the top and bottom. try this:

```
<Image Source="test.jpg" Stretch="None" />
```

You can also experiment with the other possible values for the `Stretch` property.

Comment: I've updated my question with the original image as well. I need a 3px white border to wrap the image and they are to be set at width and height both 100

Answer (score 2):

A `<Border>` does not overlay an element, it contains an element. Therefore if your border is 100px with a 3px border, there are only 94px of space left inside.

Setting an explicit size of 100 on the image means that some of it will be chopped off since the border is not big enough to show all of it. Also I see you image is not square (120x103px), meaning it will be scaled with a strange aspect ratio too.

If you really want the border to overlay on top of the same exact square as the image, then put them both in a `<Grid>` or `<Canvas>` at the same position. eg

```
<Grid>
   <Image Source="test.jpg" Width="100" Height="100"/>
   <Border CornerRadius="3" BorderBrush="#fff" BorderThickness="3px" Width="100" Height="100" Background="Transparent">
</Grid>
```

Comment: Based on what you've said: If the border has only 94px of space left inside, and my image has size of 100, why there are extra spaces occur on top and bottom?

Comment: My immediate thought would be that you are not actually setting the image height, meaning the image will be scaled with it's original aspect ratio where it is wider than it is long. If you really are setting both height and width on the image then I don't know.

Comment: All the codes have been given above. Do you think that the width and height being set to 100?